# How to extract an independent variable from an integral?

Tags: probability, integration, definite-integrals

Consider the following equation :

\begin{equation}
1=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(u)\frac{1}{(u-x)^2+y^2}\mathrm{d}u 
\end{equation}
Where $x,y,u\in \mathbb{R}$ and $p(u)$ is a probability distribution.

**Is it possible to change the equation to extract $y$ of the integral ?**
In other words, find an $f(u,x)$ such that :
\begin{equation}
y^2=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(u)f(u,x) \mathrm{d}u 
\end{equation}

Any remark, or request for precisions is always appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: May I ask what the bigger picture is here? It seems like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Does $y$ depend of $x$?

Comment: @AlexandruDinu it is very likely that it is an XY problem... I have been stuck on this problem for quite a while so I have been trying new approaches recently. I will edit my question tomorrow.

Comment: @LL3.14 $y$ does not depend on $x$. $x+\mathrm{i}y$ represents the possible eigenvalues of a random matrix and $p(u)$ is the distribution of the diagonal elements. The given equation describes the boundary region of the possible eigenvalues.

Comment: The RHS is the convolution of $p$ and a kind of Lorentzian function. Therefore, your issue has something to do with a convolutional inverse. But the LHS, a priori  function of $x$ and $y$ is in fact a constant... Puzzling...

Comment: What you say seems contradictory ... if it is a boundary region it means at least that for a given $x$, not all the $y$ are possible, right?

Comment: You say that $y$ doesn't depend on $x$ and you desire an expression $y^2=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(u)f(u,x) \mathrm{d}u$ where $y$ depends on $x$ !!! It is contradictory...